# Searching multiple sql fields

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I was wondering how I would do a search in a table on SQL for data in multiple fields. I am thinking of having one input field in HTML & PHP. In that you should be able to type in like email, name. And it will find data depending on that.

Comment: You can add multiple fields on condition or make a select with more than one table?

Comment: Sound like a good plan. Have you researched this topic? Have you done something similar before?

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%searchInput%' OR name LIKE '%searchInput%'. is that what you need?

Comment: Just a note, in SQL tables have _columns_, not fields.